# get database results on computers connected on lan using java?

Tags: java, mysql

I have a `MYSQL` Database on one computer and i am trying to access it from a different computer in Java, basically trying to retrieve a table data or something. Now this thing is quite easy on one computer using JDBC Driver.

How do i access the database from another computer on LAN using Java ?

Comment: You get the hostname or IP of the server running the database and use it in the JDBC url. Your MySQL user must have the appropriate permissions.

Comment: See i am new to this connected computer database stuff. Can you post a more detailed answer ?

Comment: @Rahul Gupta: Just look into the mysql JDBC driver documentation. You must specify the 'database location' by providing a valid TCP/IP location...